# Find and replace every text between (every) two strings?

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3, sublimetext

How can I select every text between **`base64`** and **`==`**?

Please, I have tried a whole lot of REGEX without success.

I have an exported mailbox file from Apple Mail.
I want to simply delete the image data (replace the Base64 data with nothing).

Every solution I've found is select every text between the first **`base64`** and the last **`==`**, which is not helping.

Comment: Are you sure? What have you found?

Comment: Like `base64[^<>]*==`.

Comment: So, all you needed was `base64[^<>]*?==`

Comment: Wow! Genius, thanks. Regex is still a black box to me.

Comment: i suggest removing this question, it's not asked properly and the solution is obvious and has been posted and explained many times on SO.

Comment: I think there is a vast ocean of people out there not knowing how to speak regex. They might find this useful, just as I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this in your preferred programming language. I've used JavaScript for eg.

```
newStr = string.replace(/base64(.*?)\=\=/, "")
```

Comment: I'd happy to accept this, but it does nothing. `base64[^<>]*?==` does.